# fabric.js click on button return undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, fabricjs

I'm using fabric.js to draw some stuff on canvas.

I have takePhoto variable which is

```
            takePhoto = img.set({
                left: posX - img.width / 2,
                top: (character.height + logo.height) + 25
            });
```

console.log(takePhoto) returns undefined.

Can some explain me why is happening this?
http://jsbin.com/xoxunepasi/1/edit?js,console,output

Comment: There's some other errors that prevent your code from running; "TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined

Comment: @RobQuist if you readed the code you saw i added takePhoto.on('mousedown')

Comment: And yes, its an error because takePhoto = undefined

Comment: try putting the console.log(takePhoto); just below the line where it is initiated, it will work.

Comment: If the answer below is correct, please mark it as the answer and mark this question als "answered". Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It actually is undefined. But it gets defined lateron because the function in which you set it, is a callback. - the takePhoto gets set *after* the pictures have been loaded.

You can see that because it does work like this;

```
setTimeout("console.log(takePhoto);", 400);
```

The solution would be to add your code in the callback, after you've set takePhoto.